Using @posedge to implement latches
I have a Verilog project I'm trying to reverse engineer, and I see the guy that wrote it had the following snippet to implement a latch where no clocks are involved:
/*** Asynchronous Latches ***/
always @(posedge a or posedge b)
begin
   if(b)
      c <= 0;
   else
      c <= 1;
end

and in another place he had combined a posedge and a negedge:
always @(negedge x or posedge y)
begin
   if(y)
      z <= 0;
   else
      z <= 1;
end

From what I know, posedge should only be used for synchronous logic when a clock is involved.

Is this good code?
What benefit do the unused signals in the sensitivity lists (signals a and x) provide?


These 2 code snippets describe a flip flop with an asynchronous reset (clear).
In the 1st code example, a represents the clock input to the flop, and b represents the flop reset (clear) signal.   This is a common pattern recognized by synthesis software.  Either edge of either signal is legal.

Is this good code?

Aside from the meaningless signal names, the code is valid.  If a and x really represent the same clock, then special care needs to be taken when setting the timing constraints for synthesis.

What benefit do the unused signals in the sensitivity lists (signals a
and x) provide?

These are the clock inputs to the flops.  They are omitted from the behavioral code following the sensitivity list.  Refer to synthesizable constructs for more information.

What you have mentioned in your code is not considered as Latches. they are Flipflops.
There are two things - Latches and Flipflops. Both are sequential circuits and have ability to remember. There are many types such as SR type, D type, JK type and T type flipflop and latches.
Latches are Level-triggered. Consider an SR latch,
Intially set the setpin=0 and resetpin=1, the value 0 gets stored. Later if you set the setpin=0 and resetpin=0, it retains the 0 value in it.
Similarly, set the setpin=1  and resetpin=0, the value 1 gets stored. Later if you set the setpin=0 and resetpin=0, it retains the value 1 in it.
Latches are sensitive to Levels (either 0 or 1). They are not sensitive to Edges (change from 0 to 1 aka posedge or change from 1 to 0 aka negedge)
While Flipflops are Edge-triggered. The output changes only at the positive or negative edge of the signal (usually clock signal). They have the ability to hold the state until the state changes (from o to 1)-posedge or (from 1 to 0)-negedge.
This is the verilog code for implementing a simple SR latch in FPGA:
module SR_latch(input set, reset, output reg out);
    always @(set or reset)
        begin
            if(set and !reset)
                out <= 1'b1;
            else if(!set and reset)
                out <= 1'b0;
            else if(!set and !reset)
                out <= out;
            else
                out <= 1'bx;
        end
endmodule

And this is the verilog code for implementing a simple D-flipflop(positive edge triggering) in FPGA:
module D_flipflop(input data, clk, reset, output reg out);
    always @(posedge clk)
        begin
            if(reset)
                out <= 1'b0;
            else
                out <= data;
        end
endmodule


The code you show represents how synthesis tools want synchronous logic with asynchronous set or reset modeled in a single always process. The synchronous clock (a and x) appears as an edge in the sensitivity list and nowhere else. The asynchronous clear appears in the sensitivity list with its active edge and a top level conditional branch so that the active edge sets the output to a constant ( 1 for set, 0 for reset). The inactive edge is filtered out so that only the active clock edge remains. In the code you show, this represent a flop that is asynchronously reset, and synchronously set.
